# .htaccess 500 internal error? Bad .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, internal

Bad htaccess?
Composed to run multiple functions.
Below is the code that displays the 500 internal error, no idea why?

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [OR]  
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -d  
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]



#Forbids Directory access
Options -Indexes 
#Root index file
DirectoryIndex login.php
#Rule for maintaining user url
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)/(.*)/(.*+)/?$ pages/$2.php?social_id=$1 [QSA]
#Initiallinzing user url
RewriteRule ^users/(.*+)/?$ pages/profile.php?social_id=$1 [QSA]
#direct access to login.php
RewriteRule ^login login.php [QSA]
#direct access to logout.php
RewriteRule ^logout logs/logout.php [QSA]
#direct access to help.php
RewriteRule ^help help.php [QSA]
# # Use Mod_deflate to compress static files
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
<filesmatch ".(js|css|ico|txt|htm|html|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: post error log also only then can find error

Comment: in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Try with that:

```
#Forbids Directory access
Options -Indexes 

#Root index file
DirectoryIndex login.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f  
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]

#Rule for maintaining user url
RewriteRule ^users/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$ pages/$2.php?social_id=$1 [QSA]

#Initiallinzing user url
RewriteRule ^users/(.+)/?$ pages/profile.php?social_id=$1 [QSA]

#direct access to logout.php
RewriteRule ^logout logs/logout.php [QSA]

# # Use Mod_deflate to compress static files
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
<filesmatch ".(js|css|ico|txt|htm|html|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: Just try with my last correction. And if you can see the error message in errors logs